# Use Case Diagram for Vending machine

Tags: java, c#, object-oriented, use-case, class-diagram

I want to create a use case diagram for a vending machine which has the following states:

Accepts coins of 1,5,10,25 Cents
Allow user to select products Coke(25), Pepsi(35), Soda(45)
Allow user to take refund by canceling the request.
Return selected product and remaining change if any
Allow reset operation for vending machine supplier.
Its my first time that i try to create a use case diagram and i tried to implement that
[image]

Its the first time that im trying to create a uml. Can anyone help me to create it?

Comment: what is the actual question? are you looking for software to draw UML in?

Comment: its my first time that im trying to create a uml and i want to know that my diagram is true

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to draw a [Finite State Machine using UML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A use case diagram in UML shows two things

- the actors that interact with the system
- the reason why each actor interacts with the system (i.e. the use case)

Most importantly, a use case diagram **does not** show what an interaction looks like or what steps might be involved.

For the vending machine you described, there are two actors and two use cases:

- The User actor with the use case "buy item"
- The Machine Supplier actor with the use case "reset"

The flow of actions in the use case "buy item", including exceptions like cancellation, should be described in a use case description, but that is not a part of the diagram.

Comment: Also worth to mention: 1) there is no sequence between use-cases (e.g. “choose”->”cancel”) 2)  the “states” of the vending machine (e.g. narrative+right side of diagram) are best documented in a state diagram.

Comment: Surely the Machine Supplier's reason for interacting with the system is "get money"

Comment: @user253751, the Machine Supplier does not even have to interact with the machine itself to fulfil its objective of making money. Just selling or renting a machine out is enough for that.